# Javascript parse xml from local file

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

```
    var xmlReq,
        xmlDoc;

    xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlReq.open("GET", filename, false); //synchronous GET
    xmlReq.send(null);

    xmlDoc = xmlReq.responseXML;
    alert(xmlDoc);
```

I'm trying to use the above mentioned code to load an xml from the local filesystem. the variable filename is a relative path (../Gfx/Sprite/test_sprite.xml) and works both in local and when running the page from a web server. What makes this wierd, is that I can see that the xml file loads (using web inspector in safari), but the xmlReq.responseXML/xmlReq.responseText returns null...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to use this xmlDoc = xmlReq.responseXML; inside onreadystatechange only

Comment: Tried that, and then rewrote the code (see the edit) still no cigar...

Comment: But without using onreadystatechange this wont work, your are doing asynchronous request, which means control wont wait until the request was processed so you need to bind an event listener to check for state changes of this request. So replace it with old one.

Comment: the 'false' bool in xmlReq.open should make the request synchronous... Besides, I did try the onreadystatechange the way you suggested but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webkit doesn't allow AJAX-requests on the local file-system.

Comment: Is there any other way I can load that xml file?

Comment: It should be possible to use some flash to retrieve the xml